# FaceBook Like Button click gives error

Tags: asp.net, facebook-like

I want to place a facebook like button on my asp.net web page.
I have generated code from facebook like button plugin https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script>        (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/dotnetspider" data-send="true"
        data-width="450" data-show-faces="true">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Link Button is generated properly and number of people liking the page is also shown. I am already logged in an facebook account. But When I click on like button the button turns in to red color link with text "error". The popup opened show following error :

> You can't post this because it has a blocked link.: The content you're trying to share includes a link that's been blocked for being spammy or unsafe:Body of an error/warning message. Title is: You can't post this because it has a blocked link.For more information, visit the Help Center. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.

It simple code but its not working... Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, whether correctly or not, FB have determined the page you are trying to post a *LIKE* from is a source of spam. Note that this is to do with the page you are Like-ing, so whether or not your app is in development, or where you are actually posting from, may not be relevant.

If you think this is incorrect, you can post an appeal here: http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=block_appeal

If your page doesn't yet exist (ie. you are trying to like a page that hasn't yet been published live), then that might cause an error.

And you can check to see if there are any current known issues that might be causing the problem here: http://www.facebook.com/KnownIssues

Comment: " this is to do with the page you are Like-ing"... Does it mean that if I put www.facebook.com in the data-href url it will work? I mean I tested with different urls but it does not work. But say when I visit any other website which has Facebook Like Button (and I am already logged in Facebook) and if press Like Button it works and its reflected on my site... So.. does it block my IP or localhost from my IP which i am testing?..

Comment: Amit - I'm not sure. My understanding from that error message is that the problem is with the linked page, so yes, if you change the data-href to www.google.com then the error should go away, and if the data-href points to a page which doesn't exist, or a localhost address, then it might throw that error. That said, FB errors can be opaque, and don't always highlight the real issue, so I may not be right.

Comment: Yes..Thanks..It was an url block issue. I uploaded it on other live domain and changed my facebook application site domain accordingly. Its working now.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can it be a problem that I am using a free website, e.g. something.comuv.com?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Facebook somehow sees your web page as a "unsafe" website? I am not 100% sure about this but you should give this a try. Get your website checked [Here](http://sitecheck.sucuri.net)

Comment: hi.. Thanks for your reply. My page is in development stage. I have not uploaded on any live domain. So I cant get my website checked untill I upload it. Also, I want to mention that I am using facebook feed dialog to share post (An already logged in facebook user can post on his wall -- I use App-Id n all) and this functionality is working fine. So issue in like button is some what other I guess...